# counting nucleotides script (fill in the gaps)

Tags: python

I need to complete the code in order to create a script to count nucleotides in a dna fragment. I don't know how to even begin this.

This is the exercise:

Above, we created the `counts` dictionary by hand. Replace the ____ in the following code fragment so that it is computed.

```
dna = 'AGGTCCCAATGA'
counts = ____
for nucleotide in dna:
    counts[____] = ____
for nucleotide in counts:
    print(f'{____} occurs {____} times')
```

In the second line, you'd like an empty dictionary, if you think of how you got an empty list or set, what is your guess for dict? If necessary, check the documentation.

Comment: Are you taking a Python programming course? I'd expect that everything necessary to do this exercise came up in previous lessons. Did you check your course notes or the fantastic online Python documentation to see how an empty dictionary is created?

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

That is a somewhat confusing question. It implies that you want an empty `dict`, but an empty `dict` will not work well for the code that follows. There are multiple possible answers.

In what I consider to be the best answer, you do not want an actual empty `dict` but rather one that starts with zero counts for each nucleotide. This is because the purpose of the following loop is to add up the counts. To get all zero counts, use

```
counts = {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0}
```

This works since you know there are exactly four possible nucleotides: `A, C, G, T`. Can you continue from there?

There is an alternative:

```
counts = {}
```

or

```
counts = dict()
```

You would then need to make the next line with blanks more complicated, probably using `dict`'s `get` method or the `if` ternary operator. This is more complicated than you need. Also, if a nucleotide is not in the string then it will not be printed at all in the output, whereas it seems that the problem wants to see a count of zero.

Yet another solution is to use Python's `defaultdict` class, but that does not seem to fit your problem since it speaks of `dict` and does not leave room for you to import that class.

Yet another alternative, the easiest, is to use the `Counter` object. But that would require a complete rewrite of your code, though the end result would be the simplest.

There are also other alternatives, most of which require changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary (counts) then check if that letter is in the dictionary. If yes then increment the value (+=) else initialize the value to 1. Then print the result.

```
dna = 'AGGTCCCAATGA'
counts = {}
for nucleotide in dna:
    if nucleotide in counts:
        counts[nucleotide] += 1
    else:
        counts[nucleotide] = 1
for nucleotide in counts:
    print(f'{nucleotide} occurs {counts[nucleotide]} times')
```

Result:

```
A occurs 4 times
G occurs 3 times
T occurs 2 times
C occurs 3 times
```

Comment: The `if` statements in your code do not fit into the template given in the problem statement. You could accomplish the same as your code and keep to the template if you use Python's `if` ternary operator rather than the statement. The main problem with this approach is that if a nucleotide is not in the string then it will not be printed at all in the output, whereas it seems that the problem wants to see a count of zero. That is ambiguous, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar solution to below.

```
dna = 'AGGTCCCAATGA'
counts = {}
for nucleotide in dna:
    if nucleotide not in counts:
        counts[nucleotide] = 0
    counts[nucleotide] += 1

for nucleotide in counts:
    print(f'{nucleotide} occurs {counts[nucleotide]} times')
```